# Explore the integration of ML pipelines through Azure Functions

Tags: azure, machine-learning

Integrate Event Grid, Azure Fucntions and ML services

Based on event using azure function ML pipeline need to be triggered

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried? Please provide more information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.